# Spring Integration: how to configure ObjectToJsonTransformer to add json__TypeId__ with class name instead of canonical name

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, spring-integration

I am trying to serialize a message (then deserialize it) and I do not want any of the headers json__TypeId__ or json_resolvableType to contain the canonical name of the class.
This is because I am sending the message over the network and I consider including the canonical name in the header a security concern.

Here is just the relevant parts of the code that I am using:

```
package com.test;

@Getter
@ToString
class CustomObject {
  String field;
}
```

Serializing it with:

```
    Message<?> serialized = Transformers.toJson().transform(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new CustomObject()).build());
```

The serialized message looks like this:

```
GenericMessage [payload={"field":null}, headers={id=496c110d-fdde-b03b-42c0-21f9671e29ed, json_resolvableType=com.test.CustomObject, json__TypeId__=class com.test.CustomObject, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1623417277287}]
```

I would prefer to have it like below, containing only the class name:

```
GenericMessage [payload={"field":null}, headers={id=496c110d-fdde-b03b-42c0-21f9671e29ed, json__TypeId__=CustomObject, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1623417277287}]
```

or even without the json__TypeId__ header at all:

```
GenericMessage [payload={"field":null}, headers={id=496c110d-fdde-b03b-42c0-21f9671e29ed, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1623417277287}]
```

I have a temporary solution, but I want to know if there is a more elegant one, like an annotation or configuration.
Below is the current programatic way of solving this.

Make a class that extends the jackson mapper and the override the populateJavaTypes (which was adding the headers in the first place)

```
class JsonObjectMapperCustom extends Jackson2JsonObjectMapper {
  @Override
  public void populateJavaTypes(Map<String, Object> map, Object object) {
  }
}
```

And then serialize with:

```
    Message<?> serialized = new ObjectToJsonTransformer(new JsonObjectMapperCustom()).transform(message);
```

Note: I am using spring-integration-core 5.2.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new message from transformed and remove headers you don't need

```
Message<?> serialized = MessageBuilder.fromMessage(Transformers.toJson()
                .transform(MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(new CustomObject())
                        .build()))
                .removeHeaders("json_resolvableType", "json__TypeId__")
                .build();
```

Comment: This is possible, too, but see my answer about dedicated component for removing unwanted header from the message we are going to produce. That `HeaderFilter` can be just configured to `JsonHeaders.PREFIX +  '*'`!

Comment: @ArtemBilan yeah I see - your answer is much clearer

Comment: Until Artem answered, I was not sure that this is the answer, because this seemed like a hack.. I would have expected the serialization to have options on how to function, and not to have to manually cleanup the headers afterwards, but ok :)

Comment: Well, that's exactly how that `ObjectToJsonTransformer` works: it adds those headers unconditionally. Not sure why the type info is considered dangerous, but `HeaderFilter` should do that trick if there is really that requirement. Note: Jackson allows us to add type info into the final JSON if that: `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property="@class")` for example. Therefore security problem must be handled different way, e.g. via `trusted` on the consumer side. See `JacksonJsonUtils.messagingAwareMapper()` with its `trustedPackages` argument.

Answer (score 2):

See Header Filter component: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#header-filter.

It is not clear why you use that `transform()` API direct, and not as a configuration of an integration flow, but you definitely can get a gain from the `HeaderFilter` functionality.

Consider to learn what is message flow and how to compose them with channels in between. All the info is present in the docs and in the EIP Book: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

Comment: Actually I am using a flow, but for the sake of the discussion I wanted to have a simple example.
So ok, the best I could do is: 
.transform(toJson())
.headerFilter(JsonHeaders.PREFIX +  '*'); 
Thanks!